# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit'

Tags: .net

I ma getting error like Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit' in the following code. How to fix this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        RadTab tab = new RadTab();
        tab.Text = string.Format("New Page {0}", 1);
        RadTabStrip1.Tabs.Add(tab);

        RadPageView pageView = new RadPageView();
        pageView.Height = "100px";
        RadMultiPage1.PageViews.Add(pageView);

        BuildPageViewContents(pageView, RadTabStrip1.Tabs.Count);
        RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        RadTabStrip1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Here I am getting error. pageView.Height = "100px";

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all. You need to convert the value to a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit` in a more specific manner. Luckliy, the `Unit` type has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk870bb4.aspx) with this ability:

```
pageView.Height = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit("100px");
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `Height` is not of type string but of type UnitSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit`enter code here`.

You can use the following static methods to convert to Unit:

- `Unit.Pixel(100);     // 100 px`
- `Unit.Percent(10);    // 10 %`
- `Unit.Point(100);     // 100 pt`
- `Unit.Parse("100px"); // 100 px`

The Unit structure does not have an explicit or implicit conversion from string, therefore, the error you are observing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
pageView.Height = "100px";
```

to

```
pageView.Height = new Unit(100);
```

`Height` is of type `Unit`, so you need to assign a value to it that is also of type `Unit`. To make an object of type `Unit` you need to call `Unit`'s **constructor** with `new`; one of the constructors accepts as a parameter the number of pixels that the `Unit` is to represent.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"100px";` with

```
new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit("100px");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Height on the control is of type [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx).  You want to use

```
pageView.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36akbeds(v=VS.85).aspx) doc on how to use Units. In your case:

```
pageView.Height = new Unit("100px");
```